# How to match some values of object using sinon stub

Tags: unit-testing, testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I've been writing test using sinon. During the same I wrote stub where some input parameters are passed and an object is returned. This object returns some values and a random date value generated by system at the time of execution. So need guidance on following.

1. How can I handle the same as the matching arguments are static in nature and I don't know the possible value of the date generated by actual code.
2. How can we skip certain key values of an object using sinon. i.e. say object has following values. `const object = {name: "abc", employeeNumber : "123"}` I only want to check if name is "abc" and don't need to match employeeNumber.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`sinon.match` docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/matchers/#sinonmatchobject):

> Requires the value to be not `null` or `undefined` and have at least the same properties as `expectation`.

---

From the [`sinon.assert.match` docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/assertions/#sinonassertmatchactual-expectation):

> Uses `sinon.match` to test if the arguments can be considered a match.

---

Example:

```js
test('partial object match', () => {
  const object = { name: "abc", employeeNumber : "123" };
  sinon.assert.match(object, { name: 'abc' });  // SUCCESS
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: The docs are not really clear, but I just tested this with sinon 15.2.0 and it is working as described above doing a partial match.  You can also use `sinon.match({key:'value'})` in `withArgs` to match part of an object passed in as an argument.  Or if you need to get really crazy you can do a nested match: `sinon.match({key: sinon.match('partial_match')})`

Answer (score 0):

## Use `sinon.match(..)` or `sinon.match.any`

```js
class CarManager {
  static drive(car, km) {
    console.log(`You drove a ${car.color} ${car.make} ${km} km.`);
  }
}

test('partial object match', () => {
  var spy = sinon.spy(CarManager, "driveCar");
  
  CarManager.drive({ make: "BMW", color: "red" }, 20);
  CarManager.drive({ make: "Porsche", color: "black" }, 10);

  // Accepts any type of BMW
  assert(spy.calledWith(sinon.match({ make: "BMW" }), sinon.match.any));

  // Accepts any type of black car
  assert(spy.calledWith(sinon.match({ color: "black" }), sinon.match.any));

  // Accepts any 1st argument, requires specific km
  assert(spy.calledWith(sinon.match.any, 20));
})
```